# Bounding function in the domain of the laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The following question comes from Brian Hall's "Quantum Theory for Mathematicians".

> Let $D(\Delta)\subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the domain of the Laplacian, which is given by
> $$D(\Delta)=\{\psi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n):|\textbf{k}|^2|\hat\psi(\textbf{k})|\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$$
> and assume that $n\le3$. Show that each $\psi\in D(\Delta)$ is continuous and that there exists constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that
> $$|\psi(\textbf{x})|\le c_1\|\psi\|+c_2\big\||\textbf{k}|^{9/5}|\hat\psi(\textbf{k})|\big\|,$$
> for all $\psi\in D(\Delta)$.

I was able to show that $\psi$ is continuous by showing that $\hat\psi\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802536/function-in-domain-of-laplacian-is-continuous). But my attempts at a similar procedure for bounding $|f(\textbf{x})|$ failed. Does anyone know how to get this inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** In fact you can show $$||\hat\psi||_1\le c_1\|\psi\|_2+c_2\big\||\textbf{k}|^{9/5}|\hat\psi(\textbf{k})|\big\|_2.$$
Apply Cauchy-Schwarz one way for $\int_{|k|\le1}|\hat\psi(k)|\,dk$ and in a slightly different way for $|k|>1$. ($|\psi|=1\cdot|\psi|=|k|^{-\alpha}(|k|^\alpha|\hat\psi(k)|)$.)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Do you know where the assumption that $n\le3$ comes into play? I'm thinking it's probably needed to assure the convergence of one of the integrals after applying Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @zbrads2 I actually haven't worked out the details. What I said must work for some pairs of $\alpha$ and $n$; presumably so for the numbers in the problem. Yes, $n\le3$ is going go come in showing that a certain $L^2$ norm is finite.